# There are 6 people including Carl and John. In how many ways can they arrange such that at least three people will be behind John and Carl?

Tags: permutations

> There are 6 people including Carl and John. In how many ways can they
>   arrange such that at least three people will be behind John and Carl?

I have no clue about what to do right now. Could you assist me?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

From the first three positions choose $2$ to put J. and C. there and then arrange the rest of them. Don't forget we can swap J. and C. So the answer is $${3\choose 2}\cdot 4!\cdot 2$$

Comment: I did not get how you got ${3\choose 2}$.

Comment: If you want to have at least 3 people behind J. and C. then they have to be on two places among first three places.